# ASMX SOAP Web Service creating Complex types instead of simple types

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, asmx

I am creating a SOAP Web Service using C# ASMX. I have one method which has 3 parameters.
The generated WSDL created a complex type by default. The Complex type is called HelloWorld. I want to attach the 3 parameters directly to the Method's root node. How to achieve that in asmx.

Here is the generated WSDL from my Web Service

```
<wsdl:types>
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<s:element name="HelloWorld">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="userid" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="password" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="data" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="HelloWorldResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="HelloWorldResult" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
</s:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="HelloWorldSoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:HelloWorld"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="HelloWorldSoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:HelloWorldResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

What i want to happen is the following

```
<message name="resultIn">
<part name="userid" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="password" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="data" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="resultOut">
<part name="return" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
```

Here is my Web Service class

```
namespace soapWebService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for i3DrugScreenSOAP
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class testSOAP : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld(String userid, String password,String data)
        {
            return userid + password + data;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the fix. It is called soapParameterStyle

```
[WebMethod]
[SoapDocumentMethod(ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
```

Additionally, we have to switch off the wsi profiles to None.

```
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.None)]
```

parameterStyle - Specifies how the method parameters, which correspond to message parts in a WSDL contract, are placed into the SOAP message body.

A parameter style of BARE means that each parameter is placed into the message body as a child element of the message root.

A parameter style of WRAPPED means that all of the input parameters are wrapped into a single element on a request message and that all of
    the output parameters are wrapped into a single element in the response message.